# Silly question about logarithmic properties

Tags: logarithms

As I know following statements are correct:

$a^{\log_bc} = (b^{\log_ba})^{\log_bc} = b^{\log_ba\log_bc} = (b^{\log_bc})^{\log_ba} = c^{\log_ba},$

$\log_aa^x = x,$

$\log_ab^c = c\log_ab.$

Then I don't get where is the mistake below:

$ a^{\log_bc} = (\log_mm^a)^{\log_bc} = \log_mm^{a\log_bc} = a\log_bc$

or alternatively

$ a^{\log_bc} = (\log_mm^a)^{\log_bc} = \log_mm^{a\log_bc} = (\log_mm^{\log_bc})^a = \log_bc^a = a\log_bc$

Obviously there is a mistake(s) in above reasoning, but I don't get it.

Comment: I don't understand $(\log_mm^a)^{\log_bc} = \log_mm^{a\log_bc}$.

Comment: In cases like this, where you "know" that there's a computational error somewhere but you can't spot it, it can be useful to pick particular values.  then go through the computation step by step using those numbers until you come to a false equality.

Comment: So, is it wrong? Can't do that? Why?

Comment: $m=2$, $a=3$, $b=2$, $c=16$.  Compute both sides.  One side is 81, the other is 12.

Comment: @mathdummy using parentheses might help: $\color{red}{(\log_m(m^a))^{\log_bc} \neq (\log_m(m))^{a\log_bc}}$.

Comment: Note that $(\log x^2)^2 \ne \log x^4$